# How to save Data in text file when user chooses a button

Tags: iphone, uibutton, nsarray

I want to have user select between two different buttons on a view, If the the user selects the imageOne, a label is created called "imageOne", then I'll save the label into an array using the following technique:

```
- (IBAction)saveData {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *choice = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/userschoice", documentsDirectory];
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [array addObject:imageOne.text];

    [array writeToFile:choice atomically:NO];
}
```

I'm trying to avoid using the Picker and a Tableview as I only have two choices and it will be easier for user to choose with a button. any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create the button, either in [Interface Builder](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2009/09/how-to-create-custom-buttons-in-interface-builder/) or [in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427818/iphone-sdk-creating-a-big-red-uibutton/1428188#1428188)
2. Hook up the button's delegate to [point to the controller](http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2008/Apr/msg00014.html)
3. Implement a method to do something in the controller (see link from number 2)
4. [Save data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307313/best-way-to-save-data-on-the-iphone)