# Are values stored in NSUserDefaults removed when the app that put them there is uninstalled?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults

If I put a token (a string) into NSUserDefaults, lets say as a paramter passed to a REST API that is used by the app, and the app is uninstalled, will the string remain on the device?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, it will not. I use NSUserDefaults in the exact same manner, and it will not stay after the app is deleted. You can verify this via Organizer if you need to.

It will however persist through updates. I have been using [TestFlightApp](http://testflightapp.com) for all of my beta testing, and the token (and other saved user default data) remains. Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for the TestFlightApp. I didn't had the chance to test is properly, but it looks like something very neat. 10x.

Answer (score 5):

No. You can see that the data saved is in Library/Preferences/ inside your sandbox. If you are using Simulator, see (something like) ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/00DB5581-E797-4AB0-9033-321ACD8938BD/Library/Preferences/com.me.MyApp.plist