# When the app is deleted what happens to the values stored in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have a little question regarding `NSUserDefaults`. When the application is deleted, what happens to the values stored in the `NSUserDefaults`? Do they get deleted as well?

When I remove a app and reinstall it from the app store the previous `NSUserDefaults` values are loaded?

Comment: When you delete app then nsuserdefault will be deleted. so when reinstall it you can not get that userdefault.

Comment: Do you develop the app yourself (the answer seems to be 'no')? Because deleting the app should clear NSUserDefaults. Perhaps the settings are restored from iCloud?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are values stored in NSUserDefaults removed when the app that put them there is uninstalled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520800/are-values-stored-in-nsuserdefaults-removed-when-the-app-that-put-them-there-is)

Comment: Cmon - one google search would have done it. Anyways, +1 for Chinttu RoxeN Ramani.

Comment: I have enabled iCloud for my app.so will this be a problem.

Answer (score 17):

When an app is deleted from the device all *local* data associated with the app will be deleted too. This includes `NSUserDefaults`. However any data stored at an online service won't. For example, iCloud. The app will just fetch the data again if requested to do so by the user / developer.

**Edit**

As per mAu's comment below - this includes keychain data, which won't be deleted either.

Comment: Also to mention that any items stored in the keychain won't be deleted too!

Comment: I have enabled iCloud for my app.so will this be a problem.

Comment: iCloud data is not tied to NSUserDefaults

Comment: I am using this NSUserDefaults value as a notification Badge count. Is there a relation between Badge count and iCloud?

Comment: Okay? Did you want the badge count to remain after a delete + reinstall?

Comment: See you edited your comment: no - badge count is not saved in iCould. Its part of a local notification (Unless you're using push notification) in either case, you should not be saving that sort of thing...

Comment: **please note** that NSUserDefaults persists through updates.

Comment: @computingfreak Yes of course it will. Updates do not delete any local data or overwrites any local data unless the developer does it.