# iOS how to cache data when kill application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching

I am developing a new feature for my app. I want cache all datas get from web service to read when offline. 
Current, my app can cache data but when I killed my app It didn't work.

 I saw an application https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/smartnews-trending-news-stories/id579581125?mt=8 can cache everything when killed application.

Do you have some suggest for me? 
 Thanks.

Comment: use nsuserdefault or save details in local database using sqllite or coredata

Comment: @KDeogharkar : nsuserdefaults for news app would be bad idea... let everything go in sqllite db...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [storing data locally on the iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040065/storing-data-locally-on-the-iphone)

Comment: @Fahim Parkar: Why nsuserdefaults is bad idea???

Comment: if your data is gonna be small, then NSUserDefaults is okay, but if you are gonna make news app, better to have sqllite DB instead of nsuserdefault for performance...

Comment: AFNetWorking return an id response, how to save it? and how about core data?

Answer (score 2):

The best option is whenever your webservice call is done, save the json data in sqllite and then make all operations over sqllite DB (like displaying that data on UI) & not over data that you received in json...

This is what FB do (& hence when you open the app, you see old posts without any downloads)

For images use [SDWebImage library](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Comment: how about NSCachedURLResponse? I used AFNetworking in my project. Do you have some solution for caching AFNetworking.

Comment: @ThuongNM : I think NSCachedURLResponse will get expired after some time... I never used AFNetWorking

Comment: AFNetWorking return an id response, how to save it? and how about core data?

Comment: @ThuongNM : instead of coredata go with sql lite.. its very easy to understand... check [this link](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use coredata as it is faster to access and easy to implement and if images are there then you can use the documents directory to save it and save the path to coredata

Comment: How can I override or delete old saved images?